# Counting digit after decimal c++

Tags: c++

I need to get a number from user as a double.  I, then, need to count digits after decimal point.  I have another idea in which I can change the decimal part to integer.

For example, if user entered 234.444, I would separate 0.444 using from that value using this method

```
double usereneteredvalue=234.444;
int value2=userenteredvalue;
double decimalvalue=userenteredvalue-value2;
```

but then i need to convert 0.444 to 444 which i can't do because i won't know how many values user enterted after decimal.
Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Input as a string, split on `.`, done.

Comment: Convert to a string and then find the `.`.  Then math it out.

Comment: they havent taught us about string and i need to do this using loop and condition. No erase no mod and i also dont what those methods are because i just saw them on internet.

Comment: You can't get the correct answer without using strings due to how binary floating point works. If you try to read 234.444 as a `double`, you'll end up with 234.443999999999988403942552395164966583251953125.

Comment: if you really aren't allowed to use strings then it would appear the setter of this assignment doesn't understand floating point math.

Comment: i am soo tired man , i am trying this for hours. nothing seems to work. this forum was last hope.

Answer (score 4):

Take user's input into a string, like that:

```
std::string string;
std::cin >> string;
```

then

```
std::istringstream s(string);
int before, after;
char point;
s >> before >> point >> after;
```

There is your number in `after` now.

---

EDIT:
To determine number of digits after it's better solution to use

```
int number_of_digits = string.size() - string.find_last_of('.');
```

---

The problem with "getting input in `double`" is the fact that `double` doesn't(!) store amount of user defined number of digits after the point.
It other words, your `234.444` in reality is probably something like `234.4440000000001` or `234.443999999999999`.

Comment: `stringstreams` are expensive.  If you just need the size of the decimal part then `string.size() - string.find(".") - 1` gives you that.

Comment: @NathanOliver, in practice `std::stringstream` isn't needed here, as `std::cin` is a stream as well. I just added it to specifically separate `string` reading and parsing (they could be done together).

Comment: @NathanOliver, Moreover, there is no guaranty about the number of points in the input. This way will still give two legit numbers.

Comment: @NathanOliver, P. S. `std::to_string` is almost as expensive. Choose your poison.

Comment: @JohnCvelth If they enter more than one decimal point then it really doesn't matter as it is ill formed input and both things fail.  This will also fail if the user only enters .1234.  Also, I  never said to use `to_string`.  I'm saying your entire second code block can be replaced with `string.size() - string.find(".") - 1` to get the size of the decimal part.

Comment: @NathanOliver, OP specified that he needs an `int` as output. So, the conversion (`std::to_string` style) is still needed.
`std::stringstream` is obvious overkill when all you need to do is to split a string. 
But here it's used because of integrated type conversion.

Comment: @JohnCvelth If he needs an `int` as input then why are you doing `std::string string;
std::cin >> string;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182590/discussion-between-john-cvelth-and-nathanoliver).

Answer (score 0):

You already have [an awesome C++-esque solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009792/2602718), but from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009720/counting-digit-after-decimal-c/53009861?noredirect=1#comment92922914_53009792), it sounds like you don't like strings.

If you *really* don't want to use strings, it'll be pretty ugly. This'll work most* of the time:

```
//Chop the left side of the decimal off, leaving only the right side
double chop_integer(double d) {
    return d - static_cast<int>(d);
}

...

double some_value;
//We don't really care about the integer part, since we're counting decimals,
// so just chop it off to start
some_value = chop_integer(some_value);

int num_after_dec = 0; //initialize counter
//some_value != 0 won't work since it's a double, so check if it's *close* to 0
while(abs(some_value) > 0.000000001) {
    num_after_dec++;
    //Move decimal right a digit and re-chop the left side
    some_value *= 10;
    some_value = chop_integer(some_value);
}

std::cout << num_after_dec << std::endl;
```

---

<sup>*Doubles simply **can't** store certain numbers accurately, so this will fail with things like `.111`</sup>

Comment: what did static cast did in that fucntion. i havent studied that yet?

Comment: @DoctorStrange I'm casting to `int`, which will chop everything *after* the decimal off. So if I subtract that from the original value, I chop everything *before* the decimal off.

Comment: Wow, if you are not yet introduced with static_cast, stop going to class and go read a proper C++ book. The double solution here will not work as expected and will show spurious non significant numbers.

Comment: Test it with 1.1 and see if it says 1 or [51](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49de1f7e5f3cf9c9).

Comment: all i need to do is reverse a decimal number for what i need to seperate decimal part.

Comment: @molbdnilo fair enough. Fixed with an absolute value and greater than instead of not equals to.

Comment: This is still really brittle.  What if I want to enter `0.0000000001234`?

Comment: @NathanOliver meh OP has a solid C++-esque solution above. I saw their comment there that said "Thanks but i dont know how string works" and thought it might help them to see how ugly things would have to be if they really wanted to avoid strings.

Comment: @scohe001 With the update , 1.111 --> 52. (There is no way to fix this - you can't get the correct answer using binary floating point numbers.)

Comment: @scohe001 Can you add such a mention in your answer then? To indicate that it's going to be very ugly?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher good call, some explanation is probably necessary anyways.